# Zero-inflated negative binomial model in R: Computationally singular

Tags: r, poisson

I have been comparing Poisson, negative binomial (NB), and zero-inflated Poisson and NB models in R. My dependent variable is a symptom count for generalized anxiety disorder (`GAD`), and my predictors are two personality traits (disinhibition [`ZDis_winz`] and meanness [`ZMean_winz`]), their interaction, and covariates of age and assessment site (dummy-coded; there are 8 sites so I have 7 of these dummy variables). I have a sample of 1206 with full data (and these are the only individuals included in the data frame).

I am using NB models for this disorder because the variance (~40) far exceeds the mean (~4). I wanted to consider the possibility of a ZINB model as well, given that ~30% of the sample has 0 symptoms.

For other symptom counts (e.g., conduct disorder), I have run ZINB models perfectly fine in R, but I am getting an error when I do the exact same thing with the GAD model. The standard NB model works fine for GAD; it is only the GAD ZINB model that's erroring out.

Here is the error I'm receiving:

> Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
>     system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.80021e-36

Here is the code I'm using for the (working) NB model:

```
summary(
    NB_GAD_uw_int <- glm.nb(
        dawbac_bl_GAD_sxs_uw ~ ZMean_winz + ZDis_winz + ZMean_winz*ZDis_winz + age_years + Nottingham_dummy + Dublin_dummy + Berlin_dummy + Hamburg_dummy + Mannheim_dummy + Paris_dummy + Dresden_dummy, 
        data=eurodata))
```

Here is the code I'm using for the (not working) ZINB model (which is identical to other ZINB models I've run for other disorders):

```
summary(
    ZINB_GAD_uw_int <- zeroinfl(
        dawbac_bl_GAD_sxs_uw ~ ZMean_winz + ZDis_winz + ZMean_winz*ZDis_winz + age_years + Nottingham_dummy + Dublin_dummy + Berlin_dummy + Hamburg_dummy + Mannheim_dummy + Paris_dummy + Dresden_dummy, 
        data = eurodata, 
        dist = "negbin", 
        model = TRUE, 
        y = TRUE, x = TRUE))
```

I have seen a few other posts on StackOverflow and other forums about this type of issue. As far as I can tell, people generally say that this is an issue of either 1) collinear predictors or 2) too complex a model for too little data. (Please let me know if I am misinterpreting this! I'm fairly new to Poisson-based models.) However, I am still confused about these answers because: 1) In this case, none of my predictors are correlated more highly than .15, except for the main predictors of interest (`ZMean_winz` and `ZDis_winz`), which are correlated about .45. The same predictors are used in other ZINB models that have worked. 2) With 1206 participants, and having run the same ZINB model with similarly distributed count data for other disorders, I'm a little confused how this could be too complex a model for my data.

If anyone has any explanation for why this version of my model will not run and/or any suggestions for troubleshooting, I would really appreciate it! I am also happy to provide more info if needed.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you confirmed that you do, in fact, have counts of 0 and counts >0?  Have you also checked that your x-variables do not *perfectly* predict the y-variable outcome?

Comment: "1) collinear predictors or 2) too complex a model for too little data", these are issues for any kind of regression, not just poisson. Have you tried re-running the regression with a simpler model? I'd start by removing the dummy variables.

Comment: @DanY Thank you for your advice. Yes, I checked those things. The model is actually not intended to explain much of the variance in the outcome (it's for discriminant validity; the focus of the project is traits that contribute to conduct disorder symptoms), so it definitely doesn't perfectly explain the outcome. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @AkselA Thank you, you're right. It worked when I took out all the dummy variables; I'm just not totally sure why that improves it for only this particular outcome variable and model type. Any advice in that regard? Also, my goal is to show across outcome variables (different disorders) that these personality traits specifically affect conduct disorder, and less so GAD-- so I'm hoping to keep the models consistent across disorders. The others included all the predictors including the dummy codes. I might try reducing the dummy codes by coding for country instead in each model. Thank you!!

Comment: @E.Perkins Are you sure you've "dummified" the categorical "city" variable correctly? You can confirm by comparing with the output of `model.matrix(...)`. I'm not sure about `zeroinfl` but `glm.nb` will dummify categorical variables internally, so there is no need to do that manually.

Comment: My hunch is excessively correlated IVs, and so far the dummies look like the most plausible culprit, so I'll have to agree with Maurits, but I'm also not familiar with `zeroinfl()`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thank you for your response! I am not sure at all if I've done it correctly. Can you explain a little more what you mean by comparing the output to find out if I'm doing it right? Thank you again!

Comment: Have you considered treating site as a random effect rather than modelling it with fixed effects? I'm not sure if that will be easy to achieve but it may be worth looking into.

Comment: @E.Perkins I've posted an example on how to manually dummify a categorical variable using `model.matrix`. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that `zeroinfl` is not converting categorical variables into dummy variables.

You can dummify your variables using `model.matrix`, which is what `glm`, `glm.nb`, etc. call internally to dummify categorical variables. This is usually preferred over manually dummifying categorical variables, and should be done to avoid mistakes and to ensure full rank of your model matrix (a full rank matrix is non-singular).

You can of course dummify categorical variables yourself; in that case I would use `model.matrix` to transform your input data involving categorical variables (and potentially interactions between categorical variables and other variables) into the correct model matrix.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(2017)
df <- data.frame(
    DV = rnorm(100),
    IV1_num = rnorm(100),
    IV2_cat = sample(c("catA", "catB", "catC"), 100, replace = T))
head(df)
#           DV     IV1_num IV2_cat
#1  1.43420148  0.01745491    catC
#2 -0.07729196  1.37688667    catC
#3  0.73913723 -0.06869535    catC
#4 -1.75860473  0.84190898    catC
#5 -0.06982523 -0.96624056    catB
#6  0.45190553 -1.96971566    catC


mat <- model.matrix(DV ~ IV1_num + IV2_cat, data = df)
head(mat)
#  (Intercept)     IV1_num IV2_catcatB IV2_catcatC
#1           1  0.01745491           0           1
#2           1  1.37688667           0           1
#3           1 -0.06869535           0           1
#4           1  0.84190898           0           1
#5           1 -0.96624056           1           0
#6           1 -1.96971566           0           1
```

The manually dummified input data would then be

```
df.dummified = cbind.data.frame(DV = df$DV, mat[, -1])
#           DV     IV1_num IV2_catB IV2_catC
#1  1.43420148  0.01745491        0        1
#2 -0.07729196  1.37688667        0        1
#3  0.73913723 -0.06869535        0        1
#4 -1.75860473  0.84190898        0        1
#5 -0.06982523 -0.96624056        1        0
#6  0.45190553 -1.96971566        0        1
```

which you'd use in e.g.

```
glm.nb(DV ~ ., data = df.dummified)
```

Comment: I have the same problem and this solution didn't work for me, `glm.nb` gives me a reasonable model but `zeroinfl` generates a singular hessian, although possibly cause I have too many variables (47 dummy vars) for the number of observations (496).

Comment: I reduced the complexity of the structural part of the model, i.e. y ~ x + y | 1, with x and y categorical variables, and zeroinfl does not generate a singular hessian and it gives me the same result if I dummify the variables manually. I see that it uses `model.frame` to specify the model, which I guess is similar to `model.matrix`. In summary, my guess is that there are too many vars for a two-component mixture model if too many paraemeters are estimated, but reducing the number of parameters to estimate it works fine (and this is why a model without structural zeros also works)